# Nothing Shows Up On Screen Except One Checkbox

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MatrixMult extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private final ButtonGroup OperationBtnGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    private JTextField tfA11;
    private JTextField tfA12;
    private JTextField tfA21;
    private JTextField tfA22;
    private JTextField tfB11;
    private JTextField tfB12;
    private JTextField tfB21;
    private JTextField tfB22;
    private JButton btnMultiply;
    private JButton btnAdd;
    private JButton btnSubtract;
    private JTextField tfC11;
    private JTextField tfC12;
    private JTextField tfC21;
    private JTextField tfC22;


    double A11, A12, A21, A22, B11, B12, B21, B22, C11, C12, C21, C22;

    public MatrixMult()
    {

        JFrame Window = new JFrame();
        Window.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
        Window.setTitle("2x2 Matrix Functions");
        Window.setVisible(true);
        Window.setSize(800, 300);
        Window.setResizable(false);
        Window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Window.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        Window.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel OpSelectBtnPanel = new JPanel();
        Window.getContentPane().add(OpSelectBtnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        FlowLayout fl_OpSelectBtnPanel = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5);
        OpSelectBtnPanel.setLayout(fl_OpSelectBtnPanel);

        JCheckBox chckbxAlwaysOnTop = new JCheckBox("Always On Top");
        chckbxAlwaysOnTop.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) 
            {
                if(ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                {
                    setAlwaysTop();
                }
                else if (ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED)
                {
                    setNotAlwaysTop();
                }
            }
        });
        OpSelectBtnPanel.add(chckbxAlwaysOnTop);

        JPanel pnlMatricesAB = new JPanel();
        Window.getContentPane().add(pnlMatricesAB, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pnlMatricesAB.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 20));

        JPanel pnlMatrixA = new JPanel();
        pnlMatricesAB.add(pnlMatrixA);
        pnlMatrixA.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

        tfA11 = new JTextField();
        pnlMatrixA.add(tfA11);
        tfA11.setColumns(10);

        tfA12 = new JTextField();
        pnlMatrixA.add(tfA12);
        tfA12.setColumns(10);

        tfA21 = new JTextField();
        pnlMatrixA.add(tfA21);
        tfA21.setColumns(10);

        tfA22 = new JTextField();
        pnlMatrixA.add(tfA22);
        tfA22.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblMatrixA = new JLabel("-:Matrix A");
        pnlMatricesAB.add(lblMatrixA);

        JLabel lblMatrixB = new JLabel("Matrix B:-");
        pnlMatricesAB.add(lblMatrixB);

        JPanel pnlMatrixB = new JPanel();
        pnlMatricesAB.add(pnlMatrixB);
        pnlMatrixB.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

        tfB11 = new JTextField();
        pnlMatrixB.add(tfB11);
        tfB11.setColumns(10);

        tfB12 = new JTextField();
        pnlMatrixB.add(tfB12);
        tfB12.setColumns(10);

        tfB21 = new JTextField();
        pnlMatrixB.add(tfB21);
        tfB21.setColumns(10);

        tfB22 = new JTextField();
        pnlMatrixB.add(tfB22);
        tfB22.setColumns(10);

        JPanel pnlMatrixCAndBtns = new JPanel();
        Window.add(pnlMatrixCAndBtns, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel pnlButtons1 = new JPanel();
        pnlMatrixCAndBtns.add(pnlButtons1);
        pnlButtons1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnlButtons1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JButton btnClear = new JButton("Clear");
        pnlButtons1.add(btnClear);

        JButton btnShiftLeft = new JButton("Copy C to A");
        pnlButtons1.add(btnShiftLeft);

        JButton btnShiftRight = new JButton("Copy C to B");
        pnlButtons1.add(btnShiftRight);

        JPanel pnlMatrixC = new JPanel();
        pnlMatrixCAndBtns.add(pnlMatrixC);
        pnlMatrixC.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

        tfC11 = new JTextField();
        tfC11.setEditable(false);
        pnlMatrixC.add(tfC11);
        tfC11.setColumns(10);

        tfC12 = new JTextField();
        tfC12.setEditable(false);
        pnlMatrixC.add(tfC12);
        tfC12.setColumns(10);

        tfC21 = new JTextField();
        tfC21.setEditable(false);
        pnlMatrixC.add(tfC21);
        tfC21.setColumns(10);

        tfC22 = new JTextField();
        tfC22.setEditable(false);
        pnlMatrixC.add(tfC22);
        tfC22.setColumns(10);

        final JPanel pnlButtons2 = new JPanel();
        pnlMatrixCAndBtns.add(pnlButtons2);
        pnlButtons2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnlButtons2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JButton btnShiftLeftRight = new JButton("Copy C to A & B");
        pnlButtons2.add(btnShiftLeftRight);

        JButton btnSqrA = new JButton("Copy A to B");
        pnlButtons2.add(btnSqrA);

        JRadioButton rdbtnMultiply = new JRadioButton("Multiply");
        rdbtnMultiply.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
            {
                pnlButtons2.remove(btnAdd);
                pnlButtons2.remove(btnSubtract);
                pnlButtons2.revalidate();
                pnlButtons2.repaint();
                JButton btnMultiply = new JButton("Multiply");
                pnlButtons2.add(btnMultiply);

                //Multiplications
                btnMultiply.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                    {
                        multiply();
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        OperationBtnGroup.add(rdbtnMultiply);
        OpSelectBtnPanel.add(rdbtnMultiply);

        JRadioButton rdbtnAdd = new JRadioButton("Add");
        rdbtnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
            {
                pnlButtons2.remove(btnMultiply);
                pnlButtons2.remove(btnSubtract);
                pnlButtons2.revalidate();
                pnlButtons2.repaint();
                JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
                pnlButtons2.add(btnAdd);

                //Addition
                btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                    {
                        addMatrix();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        OperationBtnGroup.add(rdbtnAdd);
        OpSelectBtnPanel.add(rdbtnAdd);

        JRadioButton rdbtnSubtract = new JRadioButton("Subtract");
        rdbtnSubtract.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
            {
                pnlButtons2.remove(btnAdd);
                pnlButtons2.remove(btnMultiply);
                pnlButtons2.revalidate();
                pnlButtons2.repaint();
                JButton btnSubtract = new JButton("Subtract");
                pnlButtons2.add(btnSubtract);

                //Subtraction
                btnSubtract.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                    {
                        subtract();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        OperationBtnGroup.add(rdbtnSubtract);
        OpSelectBtnPanel.add(rdbtnSubtract);

        //Buttons Events

        //ShiftLeft
        btnShiftLeft.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                shiftLeft();
            }
        });


        //Shift Right
        btnShiftRight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                shiftRight();
            }
        });

        //Copy C To A and B
        btnShiftLeftRight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                shiftLeftRight();
            }
        });

        //Square A
        btnSqrA.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                copyAB();
            }
        });

        //Clear
        btnClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                clear();
            }
        });


        Window.add(OpSelectBtnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        Window.add(pnlMatricesAB, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        Window.add(pnlMatrixCAndBtns, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    }//Constructor Ends

    public void setAlwaysTop()
    {
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    }

    public void setNotAlwaysTop()
    {
        setAlwaysOnTop(false);
    }

    public void multiply()
    {
        A11 = Double.parseDouble(tfA11.getText());    
        A12 = Double.parseDouble(tfA12.getText());    
        A21 = Double.parseDouble(tfA21.getText());    
        A22 = Double.parseDouble(tfA22.getText());    

        B11 = Double.parseDouble(tfB11.getText());    
        B12 = Double.parseDouble(tfB12.getText());    
        B21 = Double.parseDouble(tfB21.getText());    
        B22 = Double.parseDouble(tfB22.getText());    

        C11 = (A11 * B11) + (A12 * B21);
        C12 = (A11 * B12) + (A12 * B22);
        C21 = (A21 * B11) + (A22 * B21);
        C22 = (A21 * B12) + (A22 * B22);

        String C11Str = String.valueOf(C11);
        String C12Str = String.valueOf(C12);
        String C21Str = String.valueOf(C21);
        String C22Str = String.valueOf(C22);

        tfC11.setText(C11Str);
        tfC12.setText(C12Str);
        tfC21.setText(C21Str);
        tfC22.setText(C22Str);

        A11 = 0; A12 = 0; A21 = 0; A22 = 0; 
        B11 = 0; B12 = 0; B21 = 0; B22 = 0; 
        C11 = 0; C12 = 0; C21 = 0; C22 = 0;
    }

    public void addMatrix()
    {
        A11 = Double.parseDouble(tfA11.getText());    
        A12 = Double.parseDouble(tfA12.getText());    
        A21 = Double.parseDouble(tfA21.getText());    
        A22 = Double.parseDouble(tfA22.getText());    

        B11 = Double.parseDouble(tfB11.getText());    
        B12 = Double.parseDouble(tfB12.getText());    
        B21 = Double.parseDouble(tfB21.getText());    
        B22 = Double.parseDouble(tfB22.getText());    

        C11 = (A11 + B11);
        C12 = (A12 + B12);
        C21 = (A21 + B21);
        C22 = (A22 + B22);

        String C11Str = String.valueOf(C11);
        String C12Str = String.valueOf(C12);
        String C21Str = String.valueOf(C21);
        String C22Str = String.valueOf(C22);

        tfC11.setText(C11Str);
        tfC12.setText(C12Str);
        tfC21.setText(C21Str);
        tfC22.setText(C22Str);

        A11 = 0; A12 = 0; A21 = 0; A22 = 0; 
        B11 = 0; B12 = 0; B21 = 0; B22 = 0; 
        C11 = 0; C12 = 0; C21 = 0; C22 = 0;
    }

    public void subtract()
    {
        A11 = Double.parseDouble(tfA11.getText());    
        A12 = Double.parseDouble(tfA12.getText());    
        A21 = Double.parseDouble(tfA21.getText());    
        A22 = Double.parseDouble(tfA22.getText());    

        B11 = Double.parseDouble(tfB11.getText());    
        B12 = Double.parseDouble(tfB12.getText());    
        B21 = Double.parseDouble(tfB21.getText());    
        B22 = Double.parseDouble(tfB22.getText());    

        C11 = (A11 - B11);
        C12 = (A12 - B12);
        C21 = (A21 - B21);
        C22 = (A22 - B22);

        String C11Str = String.valueOf(C11);
        String C12Str = String.valueOf(C12);
        String C21Str = String.valueOf(C21);
        String C22Str = String.valueOf(C22);

        tfC11.setText(C11Str);
        tfC12.setText(C12Str);
        tfC21.setText(C21Str);
        tfC22.setText(C22Str);

        A11 = 0; A12 = 0; A21 = 0; A22 = 0; 
        B11 = 0; B12 = 0; B21 = 0; B22 = 0; 
        C11 = 0; C12 = 0; C21 = 0; C22 = 0;
    }

    public void shiftLeft()
    {
        A11 = 0; A12 = 0; A21 = 0; A22 = 0;
        B11 = 0; B12 = 0; B21 = 0; B22 = 0;

        C11 = Double.parseDouble(tfC11.getText());
        C12 = Double.parseDouble(tfC12.getText());
        C21 = Double.parseDouble(tfC21.getText());
        C22 = Double.parseDouble(tfC22.getText());

        tfA11.setText(String.valueOf(C11));
        tfA12.setText(String.valueOf(C12));
        tfA21.setText(String.valueOf(C21));
        tfA22.setText(String.valueOf(C22));

        C11 = 0; C12 = 0; C21 = 0; C22 = 0;

        tfB11.setText("");
        tfB12.setText("");
        tfB21.setText("");
        tfB22.setText("");

        tfC11.setText("C11");
        tfC12.setText("C12");
        tfC21.setText("C21");
        tfC22.setText("C22");
    }

    public void shiftRight()
    {
        A11 = 0; A12 = 0; A21 = 0; A22 = 0;
        B11 = 0; B12 = 0; B21 = 0; B22 = 0;

        C11 = Double.parseDouble(tfC11.getText());
        C12 = Double.parseDouble(tfC12.getText());
        C21 = Double.parseDouble(tfC21.getText());
        C22 = Double.parseDouble(tfC22.getText());

        tfB11.setText(String.valueOf(C11));
        tfB12.setText(String.valueOf(C12));
        tfB21.setText(String.valueOf(C21));
        tfB22.setText(String.valueOf(C22));

        C11 = 0; C12 = 0; C21 = 0; C22 = 0;

        tfA11.setText("");
        tfA12.setText("");
        tfA21.setText("");
        tfA22.setText("");

        tfC11.setText("C11");
        tfC12.setText("C12");
        tfC21.setText("C21");
        tfC22.setText("C22");
    }

    public void shiftLeftRight()
    {
        A11 = 0; A12 = 0; A21 = 0; A22 = 0;
        B11 = 0; B12 = 0; B21 = 0; B22 = 0;

        C11 = Double.parseDouble(tfC11.getText());
        C12 = Double.parseDouble(tfC12.getText());
        C21 = Double.parseDouble(tfC21.getText());
        C22 = Double.parseDouble(tfC22.getText());

        tfA11.setText(String.valueOf(C11));
        tfA12.setText(String.valueOf(C12));
        tfA21.setText(String.valueOf(C21));
        tfA22.setText(String.valueOf(C22));

        C11 = 0; C12 = 0; C21 = 0; C22 = 0;

        A11 = Double.parseDouble(tfA11.getText());
        A12 = Double.parseDouble(tfA12.getText());
        A21 = Double.parseDouble(tfA21.getText());
        A22 = Double.parseDouble(tfA22.getText());

        tfB11.setText(String.valueOf(A11));
        tfB12.setText(String.valueOf(A12));
        tfB21.setText(String.valueOf(A21));
        tfB22.setText(String.valueOf(A22));
    }

    public void copyAB()
    {
        B11 = 0; B12 = 0; B21 = 0; B22 = 0;

        A11 = Double.parseDouble(tfA11.getText());
        A12 = Double.parseDouble(tfA12.getText());
        A21 = Double.parseDouble(tfA21.getText());
        A22 = Double.parseDouble(tfA22.getText());

        tfB11.setText(String.valueOf(A11));
        tfB12.setText(String.valueOf(A12));
        tfB21.setText(String.valueOf(A21));
        tfB22.setText(String.valueOf(A22));
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        A11 = 0; A12 = 0; A21 = 0; A22 = 0; 
        B11 = 0; B12 = 0; B21 = 0; B22 = 0; 
        C11 = 0; C12 = 0; C21 = 0; C22 = 0;

        tfA11.setText("");
        tfA12.setText("");
        tfA21.setText("");
        tfA22.setText("");

        tfB11.setText("");
        tfB12.setText("");
        tfB21.setText("");
        tfB22.setText("");

        tfC11.setText("");
        tfC12.setText("");
        tfC21.setText("");
        tfC22.setText("");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        }
        catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e)
            {
            }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
            {
            }
        catch (InstantiationException e) 
            {
            }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
            {
            }

        new MatrixMult();
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent AE)
    {

    }
}
```

So I downloaded WindowBuilder for Eclipse Kepler today and started coding a program for Operations On 2x2 Matrices. Finally, I am done with all the stuff so I decide to run it and nothing shows up on the screen except for a single Check Box. I have no idea what happened and how that single check box shows up.
So I tried adding 3 lines to the bottom which is adding panels to the JFrame again just to make sure because WindowBuilder generates kinda illspaced code and it all looks conjusted.

Even now, nothing works except that single checkbox and I just can't figure out what is going wrong.

(FYI, I'm new to Swing so you might find some poorly written pieces of code but I am pretty sure it will still run)

I Would appreciate any help. Thanks A Lot!

Comment: `JFrame Window = new JFrame();` is a problem. `Window` is a class. You want `window` instead.

Comment: And instead of using a builder which will only cause you trouble, code the GUI by hand.

Comment: You both create a `JFrame` (`JFrame Window = new JFrame()`) and subclass a `JFrame` (`MatrixMult extends JFrame`). Which is the main window?

Comment: Also, invoke `setVisible` _after_ `add` and `pack`; oops, you forgot to `pack`.

Comment: Also, (1) you are adding the `NORTH`, `SOUTH` and `CENTER` components 2 times each.; (2) you will do better to use arrays over a lot of unstructured primitives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke `setVisible()` on your `window` *after* adding components and calling [`pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack--), which "Causes this `Window` to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents."

[image]

```
public MatrixMult() {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    //window.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
    window.setTitle("2x2 Matrix Functions");
    //window.setVisible(true);
    //window.setSize(800, 300);
    //window.setResizable(false);
    …
    window.add(pnlMatrixCAndBtns, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    window.pack();
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setVisible(true);
}//Constructor Ends
```